# Having some trouble with css hover menu position

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble with a site, and the hover state of the menu on the homepage with ie7 and ie8.

For some reason despite the z-index it hides behind the object flash box.

Can anyone take a look at my URL and see if you can suggest a fix. It's really got me puzzled. Only happens on the homepage because the menu seems to hide behind the flash video object.

url: http://yellowtulipcomms.com

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the flash embedding code:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use full doctype declaration:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

IE is very sensitive when it comes to calculating positions and dimensions without a proper doctype. This is something I have learned the hard way.

Addendum:

Also try using zoom:1 value in css rules. I can't test it on your site but I remember it helped with positioning in IE.